# How can I center items and selected item in RN Picker android?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to center android picker items and selected item? I've searched everywhere, and tried with alignItems:'center' & justifyContent:'center', but items are still aligned left (visible on photos), when I put alignSelf:'center' picker is no longer visible. Anyone have any clues?

```
    var REPORTS = [
        {name: 'Report 1', id: 'r1'},
        {name: 'Report 2', id: 'r2'},
        {name: 'Report 3', id: 'r3'},
        {name: 'Report 4', id: 'r4'},
        {name: 'Report5', id: 'r5'},
        {name: 'Report6', id: 'r6'}
    ];

    ...
        <Picker style={styles.androidPicker} mode={'dropdown'}
                selectedValue={this.state.report} itemStyle={styles.reports.iosPicker}
                onValueChange={(reportId) => this.onReportChanged(reportId)}>
           {REPORTS.map(function (reports) { 
               return <Picker.Item style={{alignSelf:'center'}} label={reports.name} 
                           value={reports.id} key={reports.name + reports.id}/>;})} </Picker>

    ...
```

styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    androidPicker: {
            flex: 1,
            color: '#6D6D6D',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            marginBottom: 20,
            height: 40, 
            alignItems:'center', 
            justifyContent:'center',
            flexDirection: 'row'
        }
})
```

Here are snapshoots of closed and opened picker:

[image: RN Android Picker closed]
[image: RN Android Picker opened]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried `textAlign: 'center'`

Comment: Yep, on Picker.Item style there is textAlign: 'center', as you can see in  code snippet, and it's not doing anything - literally, I've tried to set it on Picker style too, but it throws warning: "Invalid props.style key 'textAlign' supplied to 'Picker" ... :/

Comment: You can use native android. Look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker)

Comment: Thank you @Max didn't know I can use native android styles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to set `useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}` as this will allow you to use some styling props like inputAndroid and inputAndroidContainer, etc. then you can do the necessary styling in those styles.Take a look at the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select#styling), you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

`androidPicker: {
            color: '#6D6D6D',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            marginBottom: 20,
            height: 40,
            alignSelf: 'center', 
            justifyContent:'center',
        }`

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Would you try like below :

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    androidPicker: {
            color: '#6D6D6D',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            marginBottom: 20,
            height: 40,
            alignSelf: 'stretch', 
            alignItems:'center', 
            justifyContent:'center',
        }
})
```

Comment: Still aligned left :/ tnx for trying anyway!

Comment: on iOS, there is an itemStyle for picker item, but I think android is missing :) @Vikky

Comment: Yeah I know, and it's working perfectly on iOS - I totally agree,that is exactly what is missing here :) but I was thinking - hey, maybe someone else found some workaround or something to get same behavior on android ^^