# How to style the standard react-native android picker?

Tags: android, react-native

I am unable to style it. There is hardly any documentation on this. I want to know how to set the fontFamily. How to set the background color on the Picker.items?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html

Setting fontFamily or background color doesn't work. wrapping it up in a View and giving style attributes to View also doesn't work.

```
<Picker
   style={styles.picker} // cannot set fontFamily here
   selectedValue={this.state.selected2}
   onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this, 'selected2')}
   mode="dropdown">
   <Item label="hello" value="key0" /> // cannot set backgroundColor here
   <Item label="world" value="key1" />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It can be styled via native android. See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9430) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976064/how-to-style-the-react-native-picker-using-android-styles-xml).

Add the following code to `/res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
  <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/mydivider</item>
</style>
```

Create a file at `res/drawable/mydivider.xml` and add the following code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#29A1C9" />
    <corners android:radius="0.5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="0.1dp" />
</shape>
```

Before styling:

[image]

After styling:[image]

Comment: How do you get rid of the white background at the top and bottom of the rectangle?

Comment: I tried but couldn't so I left it as it is. Doesn't look so bad :)

Comment: I got it to work thank you! Is there any way to have multiple styles to choose from though? Say I want the font size to be larger in one picker in my app but the others are all the same. Is there a way to set some sort of attribute in the javascript code that I could use to switch out the styles it uses from the native android xml?

Comment: I am able to change the font family to "sans-serif-light" but I have a TTF file for Titillium fonts, how can I set it?

Comment: Its working but, the fontFamily(Montserrat-Regular) is not applied.Can you tell me how to remove the white space top and bottom?

Comment: working nicely except for the "gravity:center" thing, my items are glued to the left

Comment: can anyone help >

Comment: How can we set custom fonts for the spinnerItem? I am using `react-native` for development.

Comment: @Anjana did you find the answer? I cannot change fontFamily to custom ttf font

Comment: Does this work in the React Native 0.66?

Answer (score 9):

The question might be old but in case, you can use this to style the color:

 `<Item label="blue" color="blue" value="blue" />`

Comment: what about `background`?

Comment: Nice find! Anything other styles that you can modify on the `Item`?

Comment: And I'll answer my own question, there are no others. You can see that here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker-item#props

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the `style` prop, it's the style for the Picker, not the Picker items.

You can also see from the docs that the Picker has `itemStyle` prop but it's iOS only. Styling the Android Picker items can be done via native Android only.

Comment: I posted this as an issue on Github and got an answer that it can be done via native android programming. If you know how to do that can you please answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976064/how-to-style-the-react-native-picker-using-android-styles-xml)?

Comment: The one prop you do have with `Picker.Item` is `color` which is the colour of the text for the option.

Answer (score 1):

For those who couldnt center texts in picker modal in @Abhishek Nalin answer use android:textAlignment="center"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the solution. I had similar issue with aligning text in picker item(spinnerDropDown) on RTL layout. I didn't want to hardcode left/right direction in my style. This was the workaround I used.

In your res/values/styles.xml file
add

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- 
        ... existing styles
        --->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
 </style>

 <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```