# How to modify expo android styles.xml in react native app

Tags: react-native, expo

As many others before me, I'm looking for the way to customize expo android's theme colors and styles **in order to customize native components styles like DatePicker.**

I found a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976064/how-to-style-the-react-native-picker-using-android-styles-xml) [of](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9430) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker/39141949#39141949) explaining the same old thing: "Update your style the native android way!"

Ok then, but my React native project doesn't have any "res/values/styles.xml" and so on. **Creating them from scratch has no effect.**

There's one step that I'm deadly missing here, but which one?

My repo looks a bit like this actually:

```
.expo
/* a bunch of folders containing my custom js */
App.js
app.json
babel.config.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Style Sheet.`

Create a new StyleSheet:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#d6d7da',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 19,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  activeTitle: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

Use a StyleSheet:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={[styles.title, this.props.isActive && styles.activeTitle]} />
</View>
```

this is detail [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html)

To configure a style, such as `Android.xml`, you can separate it by doing `expo eject`.

When you do `expo eject`, you get Android folder.

about `expo eject' [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)

Comment: Stylesheet is out of the way since I want to style native component like DatePicker as described in the links provided. I will edit my question so it's more clear what I want to achieve. Meanwhile, could you tell me more about expo eject ?

Comment: you're going to achieve your goals through `expo eject`.

Comment: ejecting from expo is a really bad idea generally