# How to give fontSize to react native android picker?

Tags: react-native

How can I give fontSize to picker (android)? I tried to give but it's not working

```
<Picker
  style={{fontSize:20}}
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({language: lang})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the standard react-native android picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker)

Answer (score 9):

At the moment, you can't. This is what the official documentation says [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html)

> **itemStyle** itemStylePropType
>
> Style to apply to each of the item labels.

**But this only works on iOS**

On Android, you'll have to wait for them to implement it (or maybe write a PR for them :))

Comment: Can someone tell me they implemented this feature or not?

Answer (score 5):

This does the trick perfectly well. Just change the scale value.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
selectInput: {
    transform: [
      { scaleX: 0.9 }, 
      { scaleY: 0.9 },
   ],
 },
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To anyone still searching,
Here's what I found:-

Enter the 'fontSize' style property individually to every picker.item.

```
<Picker.Item style={{fontSize:12}} label={'AnyValueLabel'} value={'AnyValueName'}/>
```

Comment: Does not work for me on Android, did you test on iOS? thank you though

Answer (score 2):

They didn't add support to change the font size that way. Here is a workaround that I don't like but it seems to be the only thing that works. Here is an example.

```
 <Picker 
      mode="dropdown"
      selectedValue="en"
      style={{width: 110, height: 50}} 
      itemStyle={{height: 50, transform: [{ scaleX: 1 }, { scaleY: 1 }]}}>

      <Picker.Item value="en" label="English"  />
      <Picker.Item value="es" label="Español" />
    </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Normal for Android**

```
  {drinksArr.map((val, index) => (
 <Picker.Item
                style={{
                  fontSize: 30,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.Black,
                }}
                fontFamily="font_family"
                color={Colors.Gold}
                label={val.title}
                value={val.title}
                key={index}
              />
```

Answer (score -2):

Under the documentation; all what i found is that:

```
itemTextStyle={{fontSize: 15}}
activeItemTextStyle={{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}
```

Which works for me.

Comment: FYI this doesn't work in android (not tested in iOS).
also I don't see any reference to these props in the docs