# React-Native picker - change font size

Tags: react-native

I want to change the font size of the picker plus format the picker items.  I've followed the instructions in the following link, re-run react-native run-android, but nothing changes.

[How to style the standard react-native android picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Regarding the font size: iOS can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585253/how-to-give-fontsize-to-react-native-android-picker but not Android yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to give fontSize to react native android picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585253/how-to-give-fontsize-to-react-native-android-picker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the standard react-native android picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker)

Answer (score 1):

It can be styled via native android. See this and this.

Add the following code to /res/values/styles.xml

```
...

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/mydivider</item>
</style>
```

Create a file at res/drawable/mydivider.xml and add the following code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#29A1C9" />
    <corners android:radius="0.5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="0.1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: its work but it doesn't work with my added fonts !!