# Styling React Native Picker

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to style the text color of the items in a React Native picker. I've only been working in iOS so far, but if I could find a cross-platform solution that'd be awesome.

I've tried the following things:

Styling color on Picker

```
<Picker style={{color:'white'}} ...etc >
```

Styling color on Picker Items

```
<Picker.Item style={{color:'#fff'}} label={'Toronto'} value={'Toronto'} />
```

I've also seen some examples of adding a color property, so I tried this

```
<Picker.Item color='white' label={'Toronto'} value={'Toronto'} />
```

At a total loss here. Thanks for any insight!

EDIT:
Here's a solution - use itemStyle prop in the Picker element. I believe this is iOS only.

```
<Picker itemStyle={{color:'white'}} >
      <Picker.Item color='white' label={'Toronto'} value={'Toronto'} />
      <Picker.Item  label={'Calgary'} value={'Calgary'} />
</Picker>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker

Comment: Upvote for "Calgary". :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178266/how-to-set-up-pickers-border/69657723#69657723

try this one may help you

Answer (score 26):

To change the colour you need to use this:

```
<Item label="blue" color="blue" value="blue" />
```

Answer (score 25):

To change text color, background color, font size and other Misc stuff like margin and padding, you can use "itemStyle" like below:

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
    style={{ height: 100, width: 200 }}
    onValueChange={this.onChangeItem}
    itemStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "blue", fontFamily:"Ebrima", fontSize:17 }}
>
    {cityItems}
</Picker>
```

If you need a border around the picker, you can wrap the Picker inside a View and provide border to it. Like below:

```
<View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', borderRadius: 4 }}>
    <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedItem}
        style={{ height: 100, width: 200 }}
        onValueChange={this.onChangeItem}
        itemStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "blue", fontFamily:"Ebrima", fontSize:17 }}
    >
        {cityItems}
    </Picker>
</View>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: You have the best answer. itemStyle used to style the Picker

Comment: How to add a frame around a picker ?

Comment: @shira, please refer edited answer to apply border, the Picker does not directly provide a way to apply border style.

Comment: @Jigaroza287
Is it possible to set alternating background color for the picker items using itemStyle?
I want every odd item to have one color, and every even item to have a different color.

Comment: It's not working on Android.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned, the `itemStyle` is an advanced `property` only supported by *iOS Platform*, as you can see on [React Native docs here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker#itemstyle). Therefore, for styling the Picker items on Android, like changing the `fontFamily` can be done only using **Native Android styles**, for *now*. Then it will work for both platforms.

With that in mind, you would add a new `<style>` tag with your resources to the `style.xml` file, usually localized in the path: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`. And set it on `AppTheme` to count with the style added, e.g:

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Item selected font. -->
    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:fontFamily">casual</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dropdown options font. -->
    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">casual</item>
      <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    </style>
<resources>
```

Important Note: Sometimes the style property name in Android you are looking for is different from the one used in React Native. E.g positioning you might need to use `android:gravity` instead of *flex*. Therefore, you may require to search the *dedicated XML tag attribute on Android* in order to style it. With that in mind, translating in React Native `color` for Text fonts is `android:textColor` for Android.

**Useful links:**

- React Native Picker Android [git solved issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9430).
- [List of XML dedicated styles](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) from Android docs - Google

Comment: How can i change the textAlign?

Comment: Hi Oliver, you could potentialy use: `<item name="android:gravity">center</item>`

Comment: Yes it center text but I'm trying "left/right" it's not working with me and that's what I need

Comment: look this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android) talking about the possible values. If you wanna left/right, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/7133482)

Comment: How to add a frame around a picker ?

Answer (score 7):

Simply add the picker inside TouchableOpacity and apply styles to the TouchableOpacity.
Example:-

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[style.textFieldSmall, style.textInput]}>
 <Picker
   style={{color: '#fff', placeholderTextColor: '#fff'}}
   selectedValue={this.state.choosenLabel}
   onValueChange={
   (itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({
    choosenLabel: itemValue, 
    choosenindex:itemIndex})
    }
 >
  <Picker.Item label="Purchase" color="white" value="Purchase" />
  <Picker.Item label="YES" value="YES" />
  <Picker.Item label="NO" value="NO" />
 </Picker>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: An example would have made more sense

Comment: @Nathileo I have added an example as requested.

Comment: How to add a frame around a picker ?

Comment: @shira I am not sure what you actually mean by adding a frame but you can place it just after the <TouchableOpacity> or else you can share me a code snippet or an image depicting what you need so I can help you.

Comment: So what TouchableOpacity does? Nothing.

Comment: @Rajat can you elaborate more.
TouchableOpacity in the example is being used to apply the specific (custom) styles to the Picker.

Answer (score 3):

wrap it inside a `<View>`,

```
 <View style={styles.card}>
 <Picker itemStyle={{color:'white'}} >
      <Picker.Item color='white' label={'Toronto'} value={'Toronto'} />
      <Picker.Item  label={'Calgary'} value={'Calgary'} />
</Picker>
</View>


//Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
card:{
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 314,
    borderColor: "rgba(155,155,155,1)",
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(214,210,210,1)",
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 4
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
https://github.com/caoyongfeng0214/rn-overlay/wiki/Picker

```
itemTextStyle: { color: 'red' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try backgroundColor instead of color:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style

Comment: Hey, sorry - That of course works for background color, but I should've clarified that I am attempting to change the color of items in the picker

Comment: Okay, I should further clarify that I'm not attempting to change the background color at all - I'm attempting to change the colour of the text.