# backgroundColor not being set

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox, rendering

I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Picker, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'; 

export default class SelectHours extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let tpd = this.props.navigation.getParam('tpd', 'two');

    switch(tpd) {
    case '1':
      tpd = 'one';
      break;
    case '2':
      tpd = 'two';
      break;
    case '3':
      tpd = 'three';
      break;
    case '4':
      tpd = 'four';
      break;
    default:
      //alert(tpd);
    }

    return (
      <View styles={styles.container}>
        {tpd != 'one' || tpd != 'one/shortcut' &&
          <View styles={styles.choices}>  
            <Text>Please select a time for each period of the day:</Text>
            <View styles={styles.choice}>
              <Text>Morning:</Text>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.morning}
                style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({morning: itemValue})}>
                <Picker.Item label='1' value={1}/>
                <Picker.Item label='2' value={2}/>
                <Picker.Item label='3' value={3}/>
                <Picker.Item label='4' value={4}/>
                <Picker.Item label='5' value={5}/>
                <Picker.Item label='6' value={6}/>
                <Picker.Item label='7' value={7}/>
                <Picker.Item label='8' value={8}/>
                <Picker.Item label='9' value={9}/>
                {tpd === 'two' &&
                  <View>
                    <Picker.Item label='10' value={10}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='11' value={11}/>
                  </View>
                }
              </Picker>
              <Text>AM</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              {tpd === 'four' &&
                <View styles={styles.choice}>
                  <Text>Late morning:</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.late_morning}
                    style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({late_morning: itemValue})}>
                    <Picker.Item label='10' value={10}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='11' value={11}/>
                  </Picker>
                  <Text>AM</Text>
                </View>
              }
            </View>
            <View>
              {tpd != 'two' &&
                <View styles={styles.choice}>
                  <Text>Afternoon</Text>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.afternoon}
                    style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({afternoon: itemValue})}>
                    <Picker.Item label='12' value={12}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='1' value={13}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='2' value={14}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='3' value={15}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='4' value={16}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='5' value={17}/>
                  </Picker>
                  <Text>PM</Text>
                </View>
              }
              <View styles={styles.choice}>
                <Text>Nighttime</Text>
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={this.state.nighttime}
                  style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({nighttime: itemValue})}>
                  {tpd === 'two' &&
                    <View>
                      <Picker.Item label='12' value={12}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='1' value={13}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='2' value={14}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='3' value={15}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='4' value={16}/>
                      <Picker.Item label='5' value={17}/>
                    </View>
                  }
                  <Picker.Item label='6' value={18}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='7' value={19}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='8' value={20}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='9' value={21}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='10' value={22}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='11' value={23}/>
                  <Picker.Item label='12' value={24}/>
                </Picker>
                <Text>PM</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        }
        {tpd === 'one' || tpd == 'one/shortcut' &&
          <View style={styles.choices}>
            <Text>What time would you like to start taking your medication every day?</Text> 
            <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.once}
              style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({once: itemValue})}>
              <Picker.Item label='1 AM' value={1}/>
              <Picker.Item label='2 AM' value={2}/>
              <Picker.Item label='3 AM' value={3}/>
              <Picker.Item label='4 AM' value={4}/>
              <Picker.Item label='5 AM' value={5}/>
              <Picker.Item label='6 AM' value={6}/>
              <Picker.Item label='7 AM' value={7}/>
              <Picker.Item label='8 AM' value={8}/>
              <Picker.Item label='9 AM' value={9}/>
              <Picker.Item label='10 AM' value={10}/>
              <Picker.Item label='11 AM' value={11}/>
              <Picker.Item label='12 PM' value={12}/>
              <Picker.Item label='1 PM' value={13}/>
              <Picker.Item label='2 PM' value={14}/>
              <Picker.Item label='3 PM' value={15}/>
              <Picker.Item label='4 PM' value={16}/>
              <Picker.Item label='5 PM' value={17}/>
              <Picker.Item label='6 PM' value={18}/>
              <Picker.Item label='7 PM' value={19}/>
              <Picker.Item label='8 PM' value={20}/>
              <Picker.Item label='9 PM' value={21}/>
              <Picker.Item label='10 PM' value={22}/>
              <Picker.Item label='11 PM' value={23}/>
              <Picker.Item label='12 PM' value={24}/>
            </Picker>
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      morning: 5,
      late_morning: 10,
      afternoon: 14,
      nighttime: 8,
      once: 12
    }
  }

  methodSelect = () => {

  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  choices: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 70
  },
  choice: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});
```

This is what I am seeing:

[image]

Why isn't it all `white`?

**UPDATE**

For the `Picker` background I used:

```
...

style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}
itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100, alignSelf: 'center'}}>

...
```

Comment: probably the elements are positioned out of the flow .. why not simply addind background to body?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101451/styling-react-native-picker

Comment: @TemaniAfif can i directly access the body element with react?

Comment: @Yossi I already tried this

Comment: nm it worked i needed to do a few things ill post my answer

Comment: well actually i got the area of the picker to be white accross the screen, but there is still gray under it and above the text

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo, `<View styles=` should be `<View style=`, obviously.

**UPDATE**

I had some problems past this point, and I wanted to share that breaking up my code into more manageable functions helped clear things up, if things weren't actually solved by this, it at least helped me to identify the source of the problem:

```
  ...

  render() {

    ...

    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        {this.showMultiple(tpd)}
        {this.showOnce(tpd)}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  showMultiple = (tpd) => {
    if(tpd != 'one' && tpd != 'one/shortcut') {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>Please select a time for each period of the day:</Text>
          <View style={styles.choices}>  
            <View style={styles.choice}>
              <Text style={styles.bold}>Morning</Text>
              {this.showMorning(tpd)}
              <Text style={[styles.am_pm, styles.bold]}>AM</Text>
            </View>
            {this.showLateMorning(tpd)}
            {this.showAfternoon(tpd)}     
            <View style={styles.choice}>
              <Text style={styles.bold}>Nighttime</Text>
              {this.showNighttime(tpd)}
              <Text style={[styles.am_pm, styles.bold]}>PM</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }   
  }

  showMorning = (tpd) => {
    if(tpd === 'two') {
      return (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.morning}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({morning: itemValue})}
          itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
          <Picker.Item label='1' value={1}/>
          <Picker.Item label='2' value={2}/>
          <Picker.Item label='3' value={3}/>
          <Picker.Item label='4' value={4}/>
          <Picker.Item label='5' value={5}/>
          <Picker.Item label='6' value={6}/>
          <Picker.Item label='7' value={7}/>
          <Picker.Item label='8' value={8}/>
          <Picker.Item label='9' value={9}/>
          <Picker.Item label='10' value={10}/>
          <Picker.Item label='11' value={11}/>
        </Picker>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.morning}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({morning: itemValue})}
          itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
          <Picker.Item label='1' value={1}/>
          <Picker.Item label='2' value={2}/>
          <Picker.Item label='3' value={3}/>
          <Picker.Item label='4' value={4}/>
          <Picker.Item label='5' value={5}/>
          <Picker.Item label='6' value={6}/>
          <Picker.Item label='7' value={7}/>
          <Picker.Item label='8' value={8}/>
          <Picker.Item label='9' value={9}/>
        </Picker>
      )
    }
  }

  showLateMorning = (tpd) => {
    if(tpd === 'four') {
      return (
        <View style={styles.choice}>
          <Text style={styles.bold}>Late morning</Text>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.late_morning}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({late_morning: itemValue})}
            itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
            <Picker.Item label='6' value={6}/>
            <Picker.Item label='7' value={7}/>
            <Picker.Item label='8' value={8}/>
            <Picker.Item label='9' value={9}/>
            <Picker.Item label='10' value={10}/>
            <Picker.Item label='11' value={11}/>
            <Picker.Item label='11' value={12}/>
          </Picker>
          <Text style={[styles.am_pm, styles.bold]}>AM</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  showAfternoon = (tpd) => {
    if(tpd != 'two') {
      return (
        <View style={styles.choice}>
          <Text style={styles.bold}>Afternoon</Text>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.afternoon}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({afternoon: itemValue})}    
            itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
            <Picker.Item label='12' value={12}/>
            <Picker.Item label='1' value={13}/>
            <Picker.Item label='2' value={14}/>
            <Picker.Item label='3' value={15}/>
            <Picker.Item label='4' value={16}/>
            <Picker.Item label='5' value={17}/>
            <Picker.Item label='6' value={18}/>
          </Picker>
          <Text style={[styles.am_pm, styles.bold]}>PM</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  showNighttime = (tpd) => {
    if(tpd != 'two') {
      return (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.nighttime}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({nighttime: itemValue})}
          itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
          <Picker.Item label='6' value={18}/>
          <Picker.Item label='7' value={19}/>
          <Picker.Item label='8' value={20}/>
          <Picker.Item label='9' value={21}/>
          <Picker.Item label='10' value={22}/>
          <Picker.Item label='11' value={23}/>
          <Picker.Item label='12' value={24}/>
        </Picker>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.nighttime}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({nighttime: itemValue})}
          itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
          <Picker.Item label='12' value={12}/>
          <Picker.Item label='1' value={13}/>
          <Picker.Item label='2' value={14}/>
          <Picker.Item label='3' value={15}/>
          <Picker.Item label='4' value={16}/>
          <Picker.Item label='5' value={17}/>
          <Picker.Item label='6' value={18}/>
          <Picker.Item label='7' value={19}/>
          <Picker.Item label='8' value={20}/>
          <Picker.Item label='9' value={21}/>
          <Picker.Item label='10' value={22}/>
          <Picker.Item label='11' value={23}/>
          <Picker.Item label='12' value={24}/>
        </Picker>
      )
    }
  }

  showOnce = (tpd) => {
    if(tpd === 'one' || tpd == 'one/shortcut') {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <View style={styles.once_choices}>
            <Text style={{paddingLeft: 15, paddingRight: 15}}>What time would you like to start taking your medication every day?</Text> 
            <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.once}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({once: itemValue})}
              itemStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 100}}>
              <Picker.Item label='1 AM' value={1}/>
              <Picker.Item label='2 AM' value={2}/>
              <Picker.Item label='3 AM' value={3}/>
              <Picker.Item label='4 AM' value={4}/>
              <Picker.Item label='5 AM' value={5}/>
              <Picker.Item label='6 AM' value={6}/>
              <Picker.Item label='7 AM' value={7}/>
              <Picker.Item label='8 AM' value={8}/>
              <Picker.Item label='9 AM' value={9}/>
              <Picker.Item label='10 AM' value={10}/>
              <Picker.Item label='11 AM' value={11}/>
              <Picker.Item label='12 PM' value={12}/>
              <Picker.Item label='1 PM' value={13}/>
              <Picker.Item label='2 PM' value={14}/>
              <Picker.Item label='3 PM' value={15}/>
              <Picker.Item label='4 PM' value={16}/>
              <Picker.Item label='5 PM' value={17}/>
              <Picker.Item label='6 PM' value={18}/>
              <Picker.Item label='7 PM' value={19}/>
              <Picker.Item label='8 PM' value={20}/>
              <Picker.Item label='9 PM' value={21}/>
              <Picker.Item label='10 PM' value={22}/>
              <Picker.Item label='11 PM' value={23}/>
              <Picker.Item label='12 PM' value={24}/>
            </Picker>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  ...
```