# Remove border in bottom of the react-native Picker

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, border

I have a problem trying to remove the bottom border from the default Picker in react-native.

My code:

```
<Picker
  style={styles.pickerStyle}
  selectedValue={this.state.registerType}
  onValueChange={(item) => this.setState({registerType:item})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Vælg emne" value="choose" />
  {registerTypes}
</Picker>
```

On the image below you can see what I want to remove:
[image]

I have tried to use the `underlineColorAndroid='transparent'` properties as you will do in the `TextInput` tag, but it diden't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to style the picker directly in android. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker/39141949#39141949

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I know it was an easy fix, but a part of my design was to change the background color in the Picker and then the border is hidden behind I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best way ever, but I found a fast solution that worked fine in my project.

1. Define a **height** for `<View>` and `<Picker>`, and the container element must be **1px bigger**.
2. Set `overflow: "hidden"` para o container.

```html
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Picker style={styles.picker}>
    <Picker.Item value="1" label="Yes" />
    <Picker.Item value="2" label="No" />
  </Picker>
<View>
```

```js
container: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: 51
},
picker: {
    height: 50
}
```