# how to set custom font to picker item react native

Tags: android, react-native, picker, font-family

So far I have followed this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39141949/5392365

Currently, I am using open sans custom font for my app and in assets folder, I have all the open sans font variations. as default I use OpenSans.ttf

Here above fix the inbuilt font families has been set like this :

```
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
```

My question is how to set my custom font into that. tried just putting a name and basic tryouts but no luck. can anyone experienced with both Android and react native help here to fix this in react native?

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you solved this?Please let me know if you did this.Thank you