# Picker.Item color not working in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am new in `react-native`. I've been trying to customise the `Picker.Item` with simple color change and it's not working.

I've created a `RedPickerItem` class which wraps `Picker.Item` with default `color` set to `red`.

```
class RedPickerItem extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Picker.Item color="red" {...this.props}/>
        )
    }
}
```

and I use it like below

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.pickerValue}
    style={{height: 50, width:'100%'}}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({pickerValue: itemValue})}>
    <RedPickerItem label="Red Picker Item" value="red"/>
    <Picker.Item label="Default Picker Item" value="default"/>
</Picker>
```

but am getting below output which shows default `Picker.Item` color. The given red color is not working.

[image]

When i give the `color` prop directly like this

```
<Picker.Item color="red" label="Red Picker Item" value="red"/>
```

It works.

[image]

But that's not how I want it working. I want the wrap `method` working.

**Full source code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Picker, View} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pickerValue: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.pickerValue}
                    style={{height: 50, width:'100%'}}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({pickerValue: itemValue})}>
                    <RedPickerItem label="Red Picker Item" value="red"/>
                    <Picker.Item label="Default Picker Item" value="default"/>
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class RedPickerItem extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Picker.Item {...this.props} color="red" />
        )
    }
}
```

Edit:

I know there is this 'itemStyle' property available for 'Picker', but i need to set individual item color set for each `Picker.Item`.

So my questions are,

1) **Why it's not working when I wrap it with another class ?**

2) **How can i make it working?**

Further clarification can be asked in comments.

Comment: try using `itemStyle={{ color: 'red' }}` in `<Picker.Item />`

Comment: I want to set individual item color.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9430 which eventually leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker/39141949#39141949

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the links dave

Answer (score 0):

```
<Picker.Item color='#000'
   label={Platform.OS === 'ios'?<Text style={{color:'#000'}}>{label}</Text>:label}
   value='' />
```