# Changing Picker.Item font family React native?

Tags: react-native

```
<Picker
  // selectedValue={this.state.language}
  selectedValue="USD"
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100, marginRight: 10, justifyContent: 'flex-start'  }}
  itemStyle={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto_thin' }}
  // onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
  //   this.setState({ language: itemValue })
  // }
  >
  <Picker.Item label="USD" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="ETB" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

I want to change the font of the picker items, and i add a property itemStyle with fontFamily values. But the pickers items font is not changed.

Comment: Have you installed the font and linked it in the android xml file ?

Comment: Yeah. I checked it in a Text component and it works fine.

Comment: I am pretty sure the itemStyle is not applied to a Text component. edit: my bad it is

Comment: This will help you, i hope :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921492/how-to-style-the-standard-react-native-android-picker/39141949#39141949

Answer (score 4):

As Robbie mentioned, you can use `itemStyle` prop.

However, the `itemStyle` is an advanced `property` only supported by *iOS Platform*, as you can see on [React Native docs here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker#itemstyle). Therefore, for styling the Picker items, like changing the `fontFamily`, color, etc can be done only using **Native Android styles**, for *now*. Then it will work for both platforms.

With that in mind, you would add a new `<style>` tag with your resources to the `style.xml` file, usually localized in the path: `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`. And set it on `AppTheme` to count with the style added, e.g:

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Item selected font. -->
    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:fontFamily">casual</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dropdown options font. -->
    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:fontFamily">casual</item>
      <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    </style>
<resources>
```

**Useful links:**

- React Native Picker Android [git solved issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9430).

Comment: Could you tell me, how to add custom font (GlacialIndifference-Regular) in above android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml file ?

Comment: You have to add the *font to your project*, then you will set as `<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lobster_italic</item>`. See more instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Comment: hi Sayuri Mizuguchi, not working this solution getting error

Comment: Add a question on StackOverflow explaining all steps, adding the code you tried, steps you did, since the question is different. Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

That code should work, but I'm curious about the font name you're providing. If you're using a google font as a linked asset, that should be `Roboto-Thin` unless you renamed it yourself. Double check that the font name linked to your project is correct.

Another thing to note is that the Android default font is *already* Roboto, so you can get it's thin version via the `fontWeight` property:

```
itemStyle={{ fontWeight: '100' }} // <-- 100 is thin, 300 is light, 400 would be regular
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding this code on the `android\app\src\main\res\values.\styles.xml`

```xml
<resources>

    
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
            <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
                    
                    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
                    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
            </style>

            <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
                <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
                <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
                <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arab_font</item>

            </style>
            <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
                <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
                <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
                <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

            


            </style> 


</resources>
```

But for the fonts names you need to create the font folder on this path `android\app\src\main\res\font` and the font file name should not start with capital letter all the name should include just small letters and you have to reload the Metro sever to se the changes (reload the project from the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

**Normal for Android**

```
  {drinksArr.map((val, index) => (
 <Picker.Item
                style={{
                  fontSize: 30,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.Black,
                }}
                fontFamily="font_family"
                color={Colors.Gold}
                label={val.title}
                value={val.title}
                key={index}
```